# How to sort on multiple columns using takeOrdered?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to sort by 2 or multiple columns using the `takeOrdered(4)(Ordering[Int])` approach in Spark-Scala.

I can achieve this using the sortBy like this :

```
lines.sortBy(x => (x.split(",")(1).toInt, -x.split(",")(4).toInt)).map(p => println(p)).take(50)
```

But when i try to sort using the takeOrdered approach its failing

Comment: What's the type of `lines`?

Answer (score 1):

*tl;dr* Do something like this (but consider rewriting your code to call `split` only once):

```
lines.map(x => (x.split(",")(1).toInt, -x.split(",")(4).toInt)).takeOrdered(50)
```

Here is the explanation.

When you call `takeOrdered` directly on `lines`, the `implicit Ordering` that takes effect is `Ordering[String]` because `lines` is an `RDD[String]`. You need to transform `lines` into a *new* `RDD[(Int, Int)]`. Because there is an `implicit Ordering[(Int, Int)]` available, it takes effect on your transformed `RDD`.

Meanwhile, `sortBy` works a little differently. Here is the signature:

```
sortBy[K](f: (T) ⇒ K, ascending: Boolean = true, numPartitions: Int = this.partitions.length)(implicit ord: Ordering[K], ctag: ClassTag[K]): RDD[T]
```

I know that is an intimidating signature, but if you cut through the noise, you can see that `sortBy` takes a function that maps your original type to a new type *just for sorting purposes* and applies the `Ordering` for that return type if one is in `implicit` scope.

In your case, you are applying a function to the `String`s in your `RDD` to transform them into a "view" of how Spark should treat them merely for sorting purposes, *i.e* as a `(Int, Int)`, and then relying on the fact that the `implicit Ordering[(Int, Int)]` is available as mentioned.

The `sortBy` approach allows you to keep `lines` intact as an `RDD[String]` and use the mapping just to sort while the `takeOrdered` approach operates on a *brand new* `RDD` containing `(Int, Int)` derived from the original `lines`. Whichever approach is more suitable for your needs depends on what you wish to accomplish.

On another note, you probably want to rewrite your code to only `split` your text once.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your custom Ordering:

```
lines.takeOrdered(4)(new Ordering[String] {
  override def compare(x: String, y: String): Int = {
    val xs=x.split(",")
    val ys=y.split(",")
    val d1 = xs(1).toInt - ys(1).toInt
    if (d1 != 0) d1 else ys(4).toInt - xs(4).toInt
  }
})
```